# Python/django : Cannot import GeoIP

Tags: python, django, geodjango, geoip

I cannot import GeoIP in django. I searched and tested this error two days, but still could not know problem.

Surely, I installed GeoDjango. I'm on MacOS 10.8

following is log by tested by django shell

```
from django.contrib.gis import geoip
```

> module 'django.contrib.gis.geoip' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/__init__.pyc'

it works. even I could find geoip class at Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/base.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import geoip
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
> ImportError: cannot import name geoip
> ```

I also add django.contrib.gis to setting.py. Even I could find geoip class at eclipse shortcut.

anyway, I tested one more thing in django shell.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip.base import GeoIP
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/base.py", line 6, in 
>     from django.contrib.gis.geoip.libgeoip import GEOIP_SETTINGS
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/libgeoip.py", line 22, in 
>     if lib_path is None: raise GeoIPException('Could not find the GeoIP library (tried "%s"). '
> NameError: name 'GeoIPException' is not defined
> ```

What I missing?

Is there any way to test my error?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to install a C library in order to use GeoIP.

Here is a snippet from the file that is throwing that error.

```
# The shared library for the GeoIP C API.  May be downloaded
#  from http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/c/
if lib_path:
    lib_name = None
else:
    # TODO: Is this really the library name for Windows?
    lib_name = 'GeoIP'
```

Once you have it installed somewhere you need to reference it in your settings.py

```
GEOIP_LIBRARY_PATH = '/whatever'
```

The library was trying to tell you this, but it seems that there is a bug that prevents it from raising the correct error. https://github.com/django/django/pull/103

Answer (score 1):

Previously i was facing this issue : **from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP ImportError: cannot import name GeoIP**

which is solved when i install this package.

```
yum install GeoIP-devel -y
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by moving the virtual environment folder.

The solution is to create the environment again and reinstall the pygeoip library.