# How to import GeoIP2 successfully into a Django project

Tags: python, django, geoip

I'm trying to use GeoIP2 to determine lat/lng of all of our users based on their IP address. In my device/views.py I've got:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
```

and then at the bottom of base.py:

```
GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')
GEOIP_COUNTRY = 'GeoLite2-Country.mmdb'
GEOIP_CITY = 'GeoLite2-City.mmdb'
```

And [here's a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9hZ8.png) of the errors I'm getting

Anyone have any brilliant ideas?

Comment: Judging by the last 3 lines of your error message (you should really copy/paste those 3 lines into your question rather than using an image) your question may be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033552/cannot-import-geoip-module-in-django or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761932/python-django-cannot-import-geoip  (I got there by googling "cannot import name geoip")

Comment: Thank you! And noted. I'm still unsure about how to best use this site. And I thought I had done exactly that google search and didn't find that question (it was the first one that worked).